# Is there a way to impose a memory limit on an Android app for testing?

Tags: android, memory, memory-management

I'm looking for something similar to the JVM heap memory limit option -Xmx. Is there a simple way to do this on Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using an emulator, you can specify the **VM Heap** parameter when creating the AVD. That's the memory that standard apps will have available.

[image]

If it's a real device, however, I don't think this parameter can be changed (at least on a non-rooted one).

Comment: Thanks, I knew about the emulators, but I don't usually use them. Maybe I should just for this issue.