# How to Test Android App Under Low Disk Memory Conditions?

Tags: testing, memory-leaks, performance-testing, mobile-application

All mobile devices have limited storage options. Therefore, it is imperative for a tester to test an app under low memory conditions. To simulate these conditions, a tester has to fill device memory using dummy files. This is very tedious and time consuming process.

Is there any app or any proper steps to overcome this situation..!!

Answer (score 1):

If you're using emulator to perform test execution have variety of options to control memory availability (both RAM, internal storage and SD card) Just limit the size of the memory type you need to the application size + 5% and you'll get "low memory" environment

[image]

There are also other ways already present at Stack Overflow on how to simulate memory shortage. See links below:

- [How can I force memory pressure for Android debugging?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15588625/1254211)
- [How do you simulate low memory in the Android emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483047/how-do-you-simulate-low-memory-in-the-android-emulator)

Answer (score 0):

[You can specify the VM Heap parameter when creating the AVD.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24520590/is-there-a-way-to-impose-a-memory-limit-on-an-android-app-for-testing#24520623) However, for a real device it doesn't look like you can change the parameters.